# movement with 3D sprite in unity is not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite

I had gotten all the movement working with my ghost, which was a red ball, so i made a sprite (im not sure if that is what you call it) i was able to make one but now the movement is not working. it looks like it is on ice because when it tries to turn it goes diagonal and it speeds up when going straight. I don't know why its doing this because i'm not even putting force into it to move it. (the code):

```
 GameObject.Find("ghosteyes").transform.position = (place + vecmove);
```

thanks

Comment: that one line of code looks fine.  you can very easily debug by adding DEBUG.LOG statements everywhere.  you'll soon find the problem

Answer (score 0):

so what you can do is 3 things. first get your transform,then move it using Translate like this:

```
private Transform _transform;

private void Start()
{
    //this gets the transform that the script is on and sets it to _transform
    _transform = this.GetComponent<Transform>();
}



private void Update()
{
    float hor = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float vert = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    _transform.Translate(new Vector2(hor, vert));
}
```

**OR**
Add the Input to the position for a more fixed movement.

private Transform _transform;

```
private void Start()
{
    //this gets the transform that the script is on and sets it to _transform
    _transform = this.GetComponent<Transform>();
}



private void Update()
{
    float hor = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float vert = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    

    _transform.position += new Vector3(hor,vert) * Time.deltaTime; 
}
```

**OR**

create a rigidBody on your player. then put this script on your player. and use rigidbody.MovePosition to move your character. for example:

```
   private Rigidbody2D rb;

private void Start()
{
    rb = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    
}



private void Update()
{
    //This will take in horizontal input like A and D/ arrow left or right.
    float hor = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    rb.MovePosition(transform.position += new Vector2(hor,0));
}
```